# Explain .htaccess rules. Doesn't work for me

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have hierarchy structure of file as below:

```
/public_html/directory/
/public_html/directory/index.php
/public_html/directory/file.php
```

I want to forward the request to the most appropriate link. For example,

`mydomain.com/directory/`  to  `mydomain.com/directory/index.php`

`mydomain.com/directory/file`  to `mydomain.com/directory/file.php`

If 404 or 500 error occurs then forward it to `/public_html/error.php`

For this I have written following code in `.htaccess`

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews 

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# don't touch /forum URIs 
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

# hide .php extension snippet
#To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+).php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

It works properly if I make requests as mentioned above. But if I request for page `mydomain.com/directory/file/scrap` then it generates `Internal Server Error`

I think its because `file` is not a directory. But I don't know how to solve this problem here. Please suggest.

Also one more line is mentioned in the error output by server regarding ErrorDocument for 500 in the end. The complete output is as follows:

> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform
> them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
> that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: What should a request to `example.com/directory/file/scrap` be forwarded or redirected to?  The Internal Server Error should be detailed in the Apache error log. It is likely a redirect loop, and the log will show more detail.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski As I mentioned above, I dont have a file or directory as /public_html/directory/file/scrap. Instead of it I have /public_html/directory/file.php

Comment: So what should happen since that doesn't exist? Should it be a 404, or should it somehow attempt to find `directory/file.php`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It gives 500 internal server error. I think it finds file.php and tries to append /scrap like, file.php/scrap and generates internal server error.

Comment: You have to look in the error log. Apache will give details about the 500 error, whether it is a PHP error, a rewrite loop, or something else. Logs are the first stop for debugging Apache.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` condition also checks for "path info" style requests. So when you request:

```
mydomain.com/directory/file/scrap
```

The rewrite engine will see the file `/directory/file.php` and assume that you're making a path info style request, e.g. `/directory/file.php/scrap`

This causes the rewrite engine to loop.

You need to change that condition to:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
```

---

Oh, also, as for the `ErrorDocument` thing, I'm pretty sure that what's happening is the rewrite module is completely ending the URL processing in the pipeline. That means, directives that get applied at the *end* of the pipeline will never get applied if mod_rewrite flips out and ends all the processing. That's why your `ErrorDocument` directives aren't being applied. If you fix the rewrite issue, you'll notice that the 500 error document will work again.

Comment: Thanks friend. It really helped me. Problem is resolved. It will be very helpful if you explain this RewriteCond.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma it does the same thing as what you'd *expect* `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` to do but without the path info stuff. It's just taking the document root (e.g. "/var/www/localhost/htdocs") and appending the request URI to it (e.g. "/directory/file/scrap") then append a ".php" to the end, (e.g. "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/directory/file/scrap.php"), then makes the `-f` check.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configuration above, I would say there is a problem with `/error.php`.

Assuming there is no `scrap.php`, `mydomain.com/directory/file/scrap` will not get rewritten.

The 500 error also mentions that the error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument.

Try a static `error.html` instead of a dynamic `error.php` to narrow the problem down.

You could also log the rewrites to verify that they are working correctly:

```
    RewriteLogLevel 9
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/rewrite_log
```

Comment: I have already checked it with static error.html but the problem is still there. By the way thanks for your quick response.